# Let G be a proper k-colouring, let $\chi(G) = k$ show that for any two diferent chromatic class $C_i, C_j$

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show this, can you give me any clues? Thanksss

Let G be a proper k-colouring, let $\chi(G) = k$ ($\chi(G)$ is the  chromatic number), show that for any two diferent chromatic class $C_i, C_j$ there is an edge with one part in color $i$ and the other in color $j$

Answer (score 1):

First notice that if there exist an edge between the classes $C_i$ and $C_j$ it has to have a vertex of colour $i$ and a vertex of colour $j$ since every vertex in $C_i$ has colour $i$ and every vertex in $C_j$ has colour $j$.

Now suppose there exist two classes $C_i$ and $C_j$ such that there are no edges between them. This means you can colour them both with the same colour obtaing a colouring of the graph with $k-1$ colours which contradicts the fact that $\chi(G)=k$.